# Show DataTable in JavaScript alert box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
   ... {
        foreach (ListEntry.Custom listrow in mySpread.Elements)
        {
            DC = 
                myTable.Columns[listrow.LocalName] ?? myTable.
                     Columns.Add(listrow.LocalName);

            myDR[DC] = listrow.Value;


        }
        myTable.Rows.Add(myDR);
    }

    DataTable uni = new DataTable();
    DataTable mn = new DataTable();
    mn= myTable.AsEnumerable().Reverse().CopyToDataTable();

    uni = RemoveDuplicateRows(mn, "itemname");

    DataTable filteredDataTable = uni.Select("quantity = " + "4").CopyToDataTable();
```

I want to show `filteredDataTable` in JavaScript alertbox.
i have used used google spreadsheet as a database.

Comment: If I understand this correctly I would suggest using a jQuery dialog box instead

Comment: please share jQuery dialog box example

Comment: You should share your code.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way* to do it is to write the dataTable to a stream in XML, and then display it in an alert box, something like this:

```
System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
filteredDataTable.WriteXml(writer, true);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),"script", "alert('"+writer.ToString()+"');",true);
```

Regards.

** without using any external frameworks or libraries, besides ASP.NET and pure JavaScript.

Comment: error:Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set.

Comment: Give a name to you dataTable, call it filtered data. filteredData.TableName="filteredData";